# problem Wifi hp 530 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Bonjour,
J'ai récemment installer Ubuntu 12.04 sur mon pc Hp 530. L'installation a très bien marcher, tout fonctionne parfaitement sauf que le wi-fi ne veut pas s'activer. Le bouton du wi-fi ne s'allume pas automatiquement comme avec Windows et quand j'essaye de l'allumer il ne veut pas.Mais dès que j'allume mon pc le bouton du wi-fi s'allume pendant 1seconde puis s'éteint. Bref j'ai cherché sur tous les forums et je comprends rien à ce qu'ils disent, ça me déprime. J'aurai besoin d'un peu d'aide .
Merci d'avance.

*from translate.google.com*

Hi, I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my pc Hp 530. The installation work very well, everything works perfectly except that the wi-fi does not activate. The wi-fi button does not turn on automatically as Windows and when I try to turn it on it does not.But soon as I turn my pc wi-fi button lights up for 1 second and then s shuts down. In short I searched all the forums and I understand nothing of what they say, it depresses me. I will need some help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck with the bcm43 driver: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx